# How can i apply Faux Bold to a specific font file(.ttf) manually for generating a new font file(.ttf)

Tags: css, fonts

If text is styled as *bold* or *italic* and the typeface family does not include a *bold* or *italic* font, Editors and IDEs will compensate by trying to create synthetic bold and synthetic italic styles themselves.

- This [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcWLl.png) show the original font rendering (font is `JetBrainsMono-light`) in VSCode.
- The [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAMvx.png) show the faux bold font rendering in VSCode by setting `"editor.fontWeight": "bold"` in `settings.json`.

I prefer the faux bold font rendering instead of the original `JetBrainsMono-Bold` or `JetBrainsMono-SemiBold`. So, i want to know how to export this kind of font rendering to a `.ttf` file with the aim of applying the generated font to other editors and IDEs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly introduce the font file in css 
**Important:- Convert the ttf to woff and woff2 to eradicate any slightest of issue.**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(faux.woff);
}
```

*Include the woff2 file to in the similar way. (Optional)

And in HTML use the following snippet:

```css
div {
  font-family: MyFauxFont;
}
```

Now accordingly change the font size, weight, color in CSS etc.

Comment: Include Woff2 too as it increases the browser compatibility.